# XML parsing in c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<CompanyRoot>
  <Company>
    <Name>Courier</Name>
    <Company>
      <Name>Dhl</Name>
      <Company>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
      </Company>
      <Company>
        <Name>Test4</Name>
        <Company>
          <Name>Test5</Name>
        </Company>
      </Company>
    </Company>
    <Company>
      <Name>BlueDart</Name>
      <Company>
        <Name>Test3</Name>
      </Company>
    </Company>
    <Company>
      <Name>FastFlight</Name>
    </Company>
  </Company>
</CompanyRoot>
```

I have an xml where I want the count of xml descendants at same level ie The count of descendants of "Courier" should be 3(DHL/Bluedart/Fastflight) instead of seven is there a way possible in c#

Comment: var count = xElem.Descendants("Company").Count(); but it gave 7

Comment: That's because you have many nested tags called `<Company>`

Comment: See Jon's answer, that will let you find specific child elements

Comment: as per your logic, test 4 should also be included if you are taking first child element's text from the xml.

Answer (score 7):

`Descendants` finds *all* descendants - you just want the immediate child elements:

```
var count = xElem.Elements("Company").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Evaluate this Xpath expression**:

```
count(/*/Company)
```